# With Intel Optane M.2 can I select which drive to use

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, optane

I am going to have

1. 1TB 7200 RPM HDD
2. Intel Optane m.2
3. different m.2 SSD

if I install them all, will that third m.2. ssd be independent or is `Optane` is going to works with disks? In other words, can I specifically tell Optane to cover that slower HDD and leave other SSD alone

P.S: I Google'd hard before posting this here but couldn't find adequate answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no utility released by Intel or Microsoft for setting parameters for Optane.
Its functioning is dictated by the driver and the motherboard.

The
[documentation](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000024018/memory-and-storage/intel-optane-memory.html)
says:

> **What is Intel® Optane™ memory and why would I want a system that supports this?**
>
> When this new memory media is installed between the processor and
>   **slower SATA-based storage devices (HDD, SSHD, or SATA SSD)**, the
>   computer can store commonly used data and programs closer to the
>   processor. This allows the system to access this information more
>   quickly, which can improve overall system responsiveness.

This *probably* means that it will not apply itself to the M.2 SSD, but only
to the HDD, but there is no guarantee that the driver will do so.

Remark: Replacing the 1TB HDD+Optane by one 1TB SSD will give the same performance
enhancement or better.